# Cannot add label to Spark driver service

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, deployment

I'm trying to add a label to the Spark driver service on Kubernetes. I've seen in Spark documentation (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#configuration) that there is a configuration paramater to add an annotation to the service. Is there any way to add a label ?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the community! Could you please explain a bit more details? What have you already tried and what is the result? Have you got any errors? Based on the link you shared, this should be done by adding `--conf spark.kubernetes.driver.service.annotation.YOUR_ANNOTATION=true` when running `spark-submit`. Let me know if this helps

Comment: I was not able to find a solution to add a specific label in my Spark deployment but instead I have used the existing label spark-app-selector (could not use the label value to select the service, only the label key but that was ok in my case)